# Having issue with my menu? I want to know which class element function need to use menu responsive in bootstrap? when I shrink the browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

please visit this link  http://smclothingg.com/te/. So far  i have written code like this and uploaded to server. Now I want to know which class element I  need to use menu responsive in this code given here, Please correct me , I have written like this, please make it full responsive and please give me class element explanation , because I want to learn bootstrap properly, now only starting,my first website.and also I want to know how to move the logo and menu form left side, like this my reference website,http://neptunebuildcon.com/. when you see our uploaded file link both logo and menu is started very close to  left side, shall i need to use padding-left or which class i need to use in bootstrap. please guide me properly
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
<div class="logo">
<img src="image/logo.png"/><br/> Welcome To Lotus Groups
</div><!--endoflogo-->
</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
<li><a href="#">Lotus Construction</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lotus  Interior</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lotus  Digital</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lotus  Property</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lotus  Site</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse-->
</div><!--endofcontainer-fluid-->

cdn:
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use float property with unordered list like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right">
```

and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) may help you to learn about bootstrap basics.

Thanks.

Comment: after applying  this property, it has moved right,i have one doubt, in normal css. I use to give like width:100px or 150px according to the menu format,In bootstrap we cannot do like this?, will it automatically adjust the width , please educate me, and what about the menu and logo ,logo reside at left side very close ? how to move right further, please see my reference site, and also educate me for menu responsive, just beginning . if you can help me with proper menu coding also, really thank to you beacuse  nav navbar-nav or nav  header is there? which one i have to start first?

Comment: you can keep the logo in navbar-header, the link which i mentioned go thru the 'try it yourself / examples' given there. It will help you a lot. And yes in bootstrap no need to explicitly set  the width properties. Go thru the bootstrap tutorials, learn and then try to implement it . Here is a link to grid basics of bootstrap : [click](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

Comment: please the see the link http://smclothingg.com/te/ not reflecting properly, which we discussed.please see my reference site,  logo and menu gap . i need like that.  once for menu if you written for me. I learnt it properly  i hope u understand . I am beginner in this

Comment: I thing shall i need to use marign-auto property ? please educate me, because above given link is not reflecting properly

Comment: yes i checked your source code,
and did some changes in it

Comment: How to optimize the code? and once for menu responsive, please help me out, I am also reading in w3schools, but proper guidance should be there? which class element should i need to add first for menu responsive? i hope u understand, that why i asked to write

Comment: for responsive menus you can use javascript and css, in w3schools they have a tutorial for that, visit [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Comment: check now we need to have <div class="container"> </div> check the link ? this the output looking?

Comment: and now no need to use container-fluid class if using container

Comment: ok. hi Mohd, now main query, which div class function I have start for creating responsive menu , could you please help in that? I think this menu is very simple, because I want to learn it properly in real time. if you update with answer also , I am very happy ,

Comment: with the navbar-default class

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" alt="Lotus Groups"/><div>Lotus Groups</div></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right"> 
                <li><a href="#">Lotus Construction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lotus Interior</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lotus Digital</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lotus Property</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lotus Site</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ,not reflecting properly check that. i uploaded your code. please see once again, the logo is totally attached to left side, please see my reference link, i need space form left and rightside,

Comment: then use padding-left with the image div, and padding right with the ul

Comment: i am asking there is no class for this?

Comment: you can make your own class for this